# Mix cookie authentication ASP.NET Identity and JWT in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, jwt, owin

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 (.NET Framework 4.5.2, **not Core**) web application using default ASP.NET Identity cookie based authentication. Users can login at `Account/Login` and a cookie is set into the browser. I can protect actions using the `Authorize` attribute and even specify which Roles can access it. This is all standard stuff from the MVC 5 template.

Now I need to add an API with a few Web Api 2 controllers (inheriting `ApiController`) and I want to use JWT tokens as this will be both called by users of the web app via browser requests but also from external CLI tools. I'd like to use `Authorize` attribute with roles just like I do in the MVC controllers.

So, ideally, when an ApiController action is requested, the Authorize attribute will check if there's a valid cookie session, if it is and it matches the Roles, then, the user is allowed. If there isn't a cookie present in the request (an http request from a non-browser environment), it will check the presence of a JWT. The generated JWT payload will contain the roles the user is in, so the middleware should be able to read them from it and validate the access.

I've googled a lot but pretty much every guide out there is for ASP.NET Core.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I've ended up migrating to ASP.NET Core and used IdentityServer.